# About the use of lapply

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

Someone sent me the following code, which repeats the same command (mvrnorm) 10 times, in a list format.

```
dat <- lapply(1:10,mvrnorm, n = 10, Sigma=matrix(.3, 3, 3), mu = rep(0, 3))
```

The code works.

However, when I try the following command, it did not work and I do not understand why it does not work. I expect it to count the number of columns in 'x' ten times repeatedly:

```
dat <- lapply(1:10, ncol, x=matrix(.3, 4, 4))

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]])
```

Basically, I am trying to understand in what situation the following format works:

```
lapply(1:10, function, ...)
```

If anyone can explain to me why it works when the function is `mvrnorm` (first example) but not `ncol` (second example)?

Comment: I sorta know what bunk is saying, but why the following work? `1:10` is not passed to `mvrnorm` in the example in my original post? `dat <- lapply(1:10,mvrnorm, n = 10, Sigma=matrix(.3, 3, 3), mu = rep(0, 3))`

Comment: My question is about why the following format work for the function `mvrnorm` but not `ncol`? `lapply(1:10, function, ...)`

Comment: I am not saying that you are wrong. My question is about how to make R `count the number of columns in 'x' ten times repeatedly`, and why `dat <- lapply(1:10, ncol, x=matrix(.3, 4, 4))` does not work. (i.e., why the format `lapply(1:10, function, ...)` work when the function is `mvrnorm` but not `ncol`?)

Comment: yes, this is actually a kindof a suddle question.  I'm pretty sure that the values `1:10` are being passed to `tol`, it being the next unnamed argument to `mvrnorm`.  You can convince yourself if you try `lapply(0:10, mvrnorm,...)`, in which case it will fail since with 0 tolerace Sigma will never be considred positive definite.

Comment: I do recommend `replicate` for this type of thing, `dat <- replicate(10, mvrnorm(n=10, Sigma=matrix(.3, 3, 3), mu = rep(0, 3)), simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: You are getting the error because `ncol` only accepts one argument.  You are attempting to pass two.  Look at the first run.  `ncol(1, x=matrix(.3, 4, 4)) # Error in ncol(1, x = matrix(0.3, 4, 4)) : unused argument (1)`

Comment: if you renamed the second argument to something other than `ncol`'s formal name the error would be different though, `ncol(1, z = matrix(0.3, 4, 4))`

Comment: Right. Because the argument in `ncol` is named `x`, so when we say `x =`, `ncol` grabs that and rejects the `1`. If we called it `z` then `ncol` rejects `z` because its argument is named `x` and so that's why we see the different error there. It's not easy to explain, obviously :) But yes, as stated above you would need to replicate the matrix to get the desired list of 10 calls to `ncol`

Comment: Thanks to all. I am trying to absorb what you are saying. If you can tell me how to "like" or marked "correct" I will do so.

Comment: @RichardScriven To try out your explanation on why `lapply(1:10, function, ...)` works for mvrnorm but not ncol, I also try the following: `mvrnorm(1,n = 10, mu = rep(0, 3), Sigma=matrix(.3, 3, 3), tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)` and `mvrnorm(1:10,n = 10, mu = rep(0, 3), Sigma=matrix(.3, 3, 3), tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)`. I got the following error: `Error in mvrnorm(1:10, n = 10, mu = rep(0, 3), Sigma = matrix(0.3, 3,  : unused argument (1:10)`. So why `1` or `1:10` can pass to `mvrnorm` but not `ncol`, under the argument of `lapply`?

Comment: My actual purpose of asking this question is how `lapply` works. 
People say that `lapply` can be used to replace `for` or `repeat` but it seems to be extremely complicated to use.

Answer (score 4):

**How to reproduce that error with as few lines as possible in R:**

```
test = function(){    #method takes no parameters
    print("ok")
}
lapply(1:10, test)     #passing in 1 through 10 into test, 
                       #error happens here
```

**Throws the error:**

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]])
Calls: lapply -> FUN
Execution halted
```

The method 'test' takes no arguments, and you passed 1 argument to it with lapply.

**How to fix it:**

Make sure the function passed to sapply takes the same number of arguments that you are feeding it:

```
test = function(foobar){     #method takes one parameter
    print("ok")
}
lapply(1:10, test)           #passing in 1 through 10 into test,
                             #this runs correctly, printing ok 10 times.
```

Comment: does running lapply(1:10, test)  suffer the same slowness as a for loop ie ..              
  for (i in seq_along(X)) res[[i]] <- fun(X[[i]], ...)

Answer (score 3):

> Basically, I am trying to understand in what situation the following format works:
>
> `lapply(1:10, fun, ...)`

In all situations where `fun` has more than one argument.

Let's translate the `lapply` call to the equivalent `for` loop:

```
X <- as.list(1:10) #elements to iterate over
res <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(X)) #pre-allocate results list
for (i in seq_along(X)) res[[i]] <- fun(X[[i]], ...)
```

Now, if you call a one-argument function with more than one argument, you get an error telling you this. You should also read-up on how argument matching in function calls is done. In your example `lapply(1:10, ncol, x=matrix(.3, 4, 4))` you do a mixture of name-matching and positional matching. Since name-matching takes precedence, argument `x` is passed to `ncol` and the elements of `1:10` are then used as the second argument. That's why the error tells you that `X[[i]]` is an unused argument.

Comment: Thanks, how about `lapply(1:10, print, x='test')`. After the argument `x` pass to `print`, does the elements of `1:10` pass as the second argument for `print`? How does this argument work?

Comment: `print` got `...` as an argument. It accepts an arbitrary number of arguments. So, yes, `1:10` gets passed as a second argument and is never actually used by `print`
.